# How to treat View datas from Controller or Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, translate

First of all , i have searched on internet and stackoverflow, but my level of coding is not good enough to understand all the coding examples . 
So excuse me to ask a question that has been treated already, but i need more basic explanations :)

I am working for several weeks on C# ASP.NET and pattern MVC.

I would like to know ,once view is returned by the controller, if it's possible to "scan" the view in order to change some strings.

In fact, i would like to translate all the strings of a partialview from a method that would scan the whole partialview and change the strings into other specified strings.

For a basic example , let's say i have a simple partial view like this :

```
 public ActionResult ListeUsers()
        {

            return View(new ModelOfUser());

        }
```

And the view returned by this controller :

```
@{

   ViewBag.Title = "USER_LIST";

 }
```

And i have an RESX file where "USER_LIST" is linked to "List of users"

I would like to place the method that would check the view and translate any string into his related language string.

In this example , the string "USER_LIST" will be changed into "List of users" and displays like that on screen.

But i dont know how the controller will scan the view to get the string "USER_LIST" , you see?

I 've understood that purpose of MVC is to separate Model Views and COntrollers. Therefore Models and Controllers dont even know what Views look like !

How can i scan the View from Controller or Model ?

I dont want to change manually the strings by calling a method in the view each time i want to translate a string.

Thanks in advance for answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do that. If "USER_LIST" is in your resx file, then you should be able to change the view to:

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = @Resources.USER_LIST;
}
```

Comment: This works good ,if you manage the resource file. What does happen if my boss absolutely wants me to make that external method? Does it make sense if i tell you that we want to be able to translate the strings to several languages? like spanish, french, etc..?

Comment: The whole idea of resx files is that you have one per language you need to support and the runtime handles localisation through the use of @Resources.xxx and the like. I may be misunderstanding you, but you seem to want to bypass that and implement localisation yourself. This isn't a good idea IMO.

Comment: You are right , I tried your way and it's efficient . Thank you David!